# How To open page in new window with ajax

Tags: ajax

I Have this lisemenu in a Form

```
<select name="Exam" id="Exam">
              <option value="Hematology">Hematology</option>
              <option value="G. Urin Exam">G. Urin Exam</option>
              <option value="G. Stool Exam">G. Stool Exam</option>
            </select>
            <input name="PtID" type="hidden" id="PtID" value="<?php echo $_POST['PtID']; ?>" />
          </p></th>
          <th scope="col"><input type="button" name="button" id="button" value="Button" onclick="open_exam()" />
```

and I Have This Script

> ```
> <script  type="text/javascript">
>   function open_exam(){
>      var myurl;
>      switch($("#Exam").val())
>      {
>         case "Hematology":
>           myurl = "testspg/Hematology.php";
>           break;
>         case "G. Urin Exam":
>           myurl = "testspg/Gurin.php";
>           break;
>         case "G. Stool Exam":
>           myurl = "testspg/Gstool.php";
>           break;
>  // etc
>      }
>     $.ajax({
>       url: myurl,
>       type: 'POST',
>       data: { PtID: $('#PtID').val() },
>       success: function(data){
>         $(".myresult").html(data);
>       }
>     })
>   }
> </script>
> ```

I want to open myurl in new window instead of .myresult Class
How can I do that with this script

Comment: You don't need ajax at all for this. Just `target="_blank"` or `window.open()`.

Comment: I have Form as I change my Post